# Angular/ABP: Getting modules through component link

Tags: angular, ngfor, abp

I trying to make my frontend in Angular work, in my ABP framework.
As part of this, I want to display a dropdown component in my navigation bar, which ABP graciously has provided a function for, where you just add the component.

However, the *ngFor function, that should come through my select.module.ts file, is not loaded (I can see through debugging it never reaches the file), so it writes:

```
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

I checked syntax, and it shouldn't be the problem. I'm wondering if it is because I need to lazyload the module, as the linked component might not be instantiated with its module, or if there is a way to load it up with the linking of the component.

Image of where the component is added:

[image]

Image of the dropdown component:

[image]

Image of my module:

[image]

Or perhaps I've written my module incorrectly, or just failed to understand a basic principle of Angular?
BrowserModule is imported in app.module.ts

Comment: I have had slight progress, in the sense that if I load the module in with app.module.ts 'imports' I can see that the code is run through, but it isn't activated when the component then is run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import `BrowserModule` too.

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
 import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

 // ...

 imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule, //...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. I tried, although I think it is already imported in my app.module.ts (maybe I should have mentioned that), but it had no effect :/ - I'm pretty sure the code never enters my select.module.ts file :(

Comment: A weird error when I tried though: 
Cannot declare 'BrowserModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `BrowserModule` in the application’s main module and also import `CommonModule` in the child module.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ....
        ....
```

**select.module.ts**

```
...
...
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Sadly it already is imported into app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

It works now, after I added my module to the app.module.ts, and completely (not just hot-loaded) reloaded my build.